# New UIDatePicker as inputView

Tags: swift, uikit, uidatepicker

With iOS 13 and earlier we could use UIDatePicker as inputView but what now ?

I tried with ios14 and nothing append when the textfield is tapped.

```swift
var timePicker = UIDatePicker()
self.timePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.wheels
self.timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.time
self.timePicker.minuteInterval = 5
self.startTimeTxtField.inputView = self.timePicker
```

Is it normal ?

Comment: If the last line is what you want, I don't think that is going to happen.

Comment: what do you mean @ElTomato ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently, this is currently a known issue. the workaround is to call `sizeToFit` on the date picker before assigning it as input view.

**Swift**

```
let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
datePicker.datePickerMode = .time
datePicker.locale = .current
if #available(iOS 14, *) {
    datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
    datePicker.sizeToFit()
}
textField.inputView = datePicker
```

**Objective-C**

```
if (@available(iOS 14.0, *)) {
    [datePicker setPreferredDatePickerStyle:UIDatePickerStyleWheels];
    [datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDate]; //optional
    [datePicker sizeToFit];
}
```

See here for the answer from apple [forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652943).

Answer (score 2):

```
var datePickerView = UIDatePicker()   
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    datePickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: ScreenWidth, height: 250.0)
    datePickerView.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = .date
} else {
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = .date
}
```

Comment: You can take _datePickerView.datePickerMode = .date_ out of the if-else

Answer (score 0):

This is Work for me

```
      let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date //change the mode
        datePicker.locale = .current
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
            datePicker.sizeToFit()
        }
        birthdateTF.inputView = datePicker
```